# How to get more than 10 search results from the IMDB API?

Tags: python, json, api, request, imdb

I am trying to suggest movies to an user who has entered a movie genre, e.g. "horror", "sci-fi", etc.
For this, I have written a function that makes an API call towards the IMDB API:

```
import requests
def search_movies(search, api_key):
    movies = []
    url = "https://imdb-api.com/API/SearchMovie/"+api_key+"/"+search
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    results = data['results']
    for result in results:
        movies.append(result['title'])
    return(movies)
```

The API only returns 10 search results, which is not enough for what I am trying to achieve. Is there a way to increase this number? I was unable to find any parameters for this on Swagger, and pagination also doesn't seem to be an option, as the request is not made via URL parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get more results from that **unofficial** web service.
I believe it is better to use the official [IMDb API](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?FULFILLMENT_OPTION_TYPE=DATA_EXCHANGE&CREATOR=0af153a3-339f-48c2-8b42-3b9fa26d3367&DATA_AVAILABLE_THROUGH=API_GATEWAY_APIS&filters=FULFILLMENT_OPTION_TYPE%2CCREATOR%2CDATA_AVAILABLE_THROUGH) as stated on the [official website](https://developer.imdb.com/).

From the IMDb developer website:

> Get the latest IMDb data on-demand through our new GraphQL-backed API. Available exclusively via [AWS Data Exchange](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?FULFILLMENT_OPTION_TYPE=DATA_EXCHANGE&CREATOR=0af153a3-339f-48c2-8b42-3b9fa26d3367&DATA_AVAILABLE_THROUGH=API_GATEWAY_APIS&filters=FULFILLMENT_OPTION_TYPE%2CCREATOR%2CDATA_AVAILABLE_THROUGH)

Comment: Am I wrong or does the actual AWS IMDB API cost +$50,000? I just can't wrap my head around how to understand the AWS pricing quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AdvancedSearch, which returns up to 250 items.
https://imdb-api.com/api#AdvancedSearch-header

Sample:

```
https://imdb-api.com/API/AdvancedSearch/{API_KEY}?title={TITLE_FOR_SEARCH}&count=250
https://imdb-api.com/API/AdvancedSearch/{API_KEY}?title={TITLE_FOR_SEARCH}&title_type=tv_series&genres=action,adventure&count=250
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try features of [PyMovieDb](https://pypi.org/project/PyMovieDb/), It is a free python module for IMDB